# Responsive CSS: Positioning columns always next to each other

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

On desktop there are 4 columns next to eachother, on tablets only 2 columns next to eachother.
Somehow the 2 columns won't get aligned how they should be.

I'm using 12 columns in total. col-x is for desktop, col-s-x is used for tablets.

Desktop design works as intended:
[image: Desktop]

Tablet version:
[image: tablet fail]

Only when I remove some text of the first column, the second row's columns are placed next to eachother:
[image: tablet how it should be]

```css
*
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

[class*="col-"]
{
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
    /*border: 1px solid red;*/
}

.row::after
{
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}

/* For mobile phones: */
[class*="col-"]
{
    width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px)
{
    /* For tablets: */
    .col-s-1 {width: 8.33%;}
    .col-s-2 {width: 16.66%;}
    .col-s-3 {width: 25%;}
    .col-s-4 {width: 33.33%;}
    .col-s-5 {width: 41.66%;}
    .col-s-6 {width: 50%;}
    .col-s-7 {width: 58.33%;}
    .col-s-8 {width: 66.66%;}
    .col-s-9 {width: 75%;}
    .col-s-10 {width: 83.33%;}
    .col-s-11 {width: 91.66%;}
    .col-s-12 {width: 100%;}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px)
{
    /* For desktop: */
    .col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
    .col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
    .col-3 {width: 25%;}
    .col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
    .col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
    .col-6 {width: 50%;}
    .col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
    .col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
    .col-9 {width: 75%;}
    .col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
    .col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
    .col-12 {width: 100%;}
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3 col-s-6">text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text   
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 col-s-6">text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text bla bla blu blo bla bla bltext text text text text text text text 
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 col-s-6">text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</div>
  <div class="col-3 col-s-6">text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text bla bla bla</div>
</div>
```

I've searched for a while, but I don't know how to call this type of behaviour to research more specifically.

When there is a second row div, it will get aligned perfectly on tablets, but it crashes the desktop version.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: That's how float works. While you could fix it by adding appropriate `clear:left`s to your media query, it's just the wrong choice of layout tool.

Comment: Do you know of any practices that still enable stating the preferred layout in HTML, like in my example (4x col-3 on desktop, 2x col-6 on tablet, 1 col per row on mobile)?
I tried the grid solutions from the other answers, but to me it looks very static and overloaded creating specific classes + multiple media queries. Let's say on a page there are not only 4/2/1, but also 8/4/2/1, 6/3/1, 12/6/3/1 etc. columns per row. What would be the best-practice here? Is there a way to avoid creating separate container classes + 3 or 4 media queries for each of those rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure quite what you'd expect from 8/4/2/1 if you've got a 12 column layout, but if what you're aiming for is an even division of elements across n columns where n varies by screen width, and where the CSS is described as efficiently as possible, I suggest something like this:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  display: grid;
  --ncols: 1;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--ncols), auto);

  /* For tablets: */
  @media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    --ncols: var(--tablet-ncols, 1);
  }

  /* For desktop */
  @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    --ncols: var(--desktop-ncols, var(--tablet-ncols, 1));
  }
}

.row > * {
    padding: 15px;
    /*border: 1px solid red;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="row" style="--tablet-ncols:2; --desktop-ncols:4">
  <div>1 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text   
  </div>
  <div>2 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text bla bla blu blo bla bla bltext text text text text text text text 
  </div>
  <div>3 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</div>
  <div>4 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text bla bla bla</div>
</div>
<div class="row"  style="--tablet-ncols:3; --desktop-ncols:6">
  <div>1 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text   
  </div>
  <div>2 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text bla bla blu blo bla bla bltext text text text text text text text 
  </div>
  <div>3 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</div>
  <div>4 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text bla bla bla</div>
  <div>5 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</div>
  <div>6 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text bla bla bla</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! That is the versatile solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The simplicity and beauty of pure CSS.

```css
body {
  margin: 1em;
  background: aliceblue;
}
.d1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  gap: 1em;
}
@media (min-width: 1250px) {
  .d1 {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
  <div>
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text   
  </div>
  <div>
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text bla bla blu blo bla bla bltext text text text text text text text 
  </div>
  <div>
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
  </div>
  <div>
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text bla bla bla
  </div>
</div>
```

Any front-end library which is still using floats for its default layout mechanisms is a dinosaur.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a practicable way to define the grid-pattern in HTML, to avoid hardcoding all possibilities in CSS? (like in my example: HTML defines 4 columns per row for desktop, 2 for tablets)

Comment: Reading between the lines, what I think you're asking is whether this can be done in a boostrappy or tailwindy way using generic classes, rather than creating your own custom classes? Possibly, but surely there is a limit to what generic classes can do? Surely custom classes are still useful, particularly when doing more complex layouts? A mix of custom and generic classes is probably the optimum scenario?

Comment: What I'm wondering is if there is any scheme which doesn't require creating lots of classes and media queries. In this case I need 4 or 2 or 1 element per row, which involves creating a container class and 2 media queries. Let's say there are a couple of rows more that also contain 8/4/2/1 or 6/3/1 each. That would require loads of very specific classes and media queries. So I'm wondering if there is an elegant way to just state the design in HTML (like using 4x col-3 on desktop, 2x col-s-6 on tablet), without creating extra stylesheet elements + mediaqueries?

Answer (score 1):

i just copy pasted your entire code along with CSS inside a React App and it's working absolutely fine.
If it's not working for your case, I can suggest you to use a grid layout.
That automatically handles such reponsive issues out of the box, you just have to mention the numer of colums that you want.

Here is an example of how you can do that:

```
<div className="container">
      <div className="column One">Column 1</div>
      <div className="column Two">Column 2</div>
      <div className="column Three">Column 3</div>
</div>
```

And then you can use the CSS as follows:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(250px, 1fr));
}

.column {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

In case you want to use different number of columns for different screen sizes,
then you can use media queries and change the number inside the **repeat(<change_this_number>, minmax(min-width-of-column-you-want, 1fr))** property.

Comment: I've amended the question slightly so that the problem reproduces correctly in the stack snippet. However, that invalidates the first sentence and a half of your answer, so you might want to remove that. But it doesn't materially affect the correctness of this answer.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a practicable way to define the grid-pattern in HTML, to avoid hardcoding all combinations + media queries in CSS? (like in my example: HTML defines 4 columns per row for desktop, 2 for tablets)

Comment: @Orca37 Yes there is a way to let your brower handle the number of columns automatically.
You can just replace the number with this "auto-fit" property
repeat(autofit, minmax(250px, 1fr)).
It will work for the use case you want.

Comment: I tried "grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));". Now either 1-4 columns are displayed per row. Is there a way to disable displaying 3 + 1 columns? In terms of consistent looks it should be 4, 2 or just 1 column per row.
While it works to create a class as a grid container and using multiple media queries, I find it a bit too static to create a class + multiple media queries for every row on the website.

Comment: @Orca37 Then there is no other way but to add media queries for each screen size. The computer cannot automatically know that you want 3 columns for desktop and 2 for table.